# (Flex 4.5) Renderer for s:Label or s:TextArea on new .mxml

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, adobe, builder

I have a one question, because I`m not a programmer, I use only tutorials for teaching Flex and programming in his.

Is possible to make new render file for s:Label or s:Text property? Because I make a small RSS application for mobile and I have this code for showing images from description of RSS items (this code is located on DetailsView.mxml): var descArr:Array = rdesc.split("src="); var resArr:Array = descArr[1].split(".jpg"); var resArr2:Array = resArr[0].split("\""); rimage = resArr2[1] + ".jpg";

In new renderer file I will hide html tags, because if I use this code: var p:RegExp = /(,

So, I need render on new .mxml document with same code of DetailsView, but in new render (if it possible) I use this RegExp for hiding html text… How I set s:Label or s:Text to show renderer from new document?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible to make new render file for s:Label or s:Text property?

No!  Renderers only exist in list based classes or with DataGroups.  [You can read more about itemRenderers and what they do here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html).

Now if you want to make a component that includes text and images and can be used as a renderer, that is possible.  [Read more about creating components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4bebcd66a74275c35bf45738120d4f86190-8000.html).